# EVM Exam Question

Tags: evm

[image]

I am trying to find the CV of Maio(May) but my question is. since the "Plano Preminiar" is already finished does it count for the total?

Another question. "Plano Global" had a PV in Abril(April) of 12.000 and an AC of 13.000 and in Maio it has a AC of (24.000) but it is really 12.000 since 24.000 - 12.000 = 12.000. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

I won't provide you the answer but here is a clue: costs are cumulative when calculating earned value indices. This clue applies to both questions.